# Is it possible to check if the property value has changed in the view model without comparing it with the initial bound value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application where user can change the default settings.
I have a dialog (preference dialog) with many tabs. Each tab is bound to a separate view model. Each tab has different settings of the application.

As per the current implementation, when use clicks "OK" in the dialog, irrespective of what user has changed, each view model’s "Save" method gets called and it saves the current bound property value to a file.

Now, the problem is, if the user has not made any changes still it saves the value.

How to check if the values are changed or not. I thought for each property in view models, I will set a property called IsDirty and check if IsDirty is true for that view model,  then save the changes.

Current implementation of the property (btw, there are many such property in each view models):

```
  public bool ShowTaskBar {get; set;}
```

This property is bound to view. Whenever user presses "OK" in the preference dialog, the "Save" method picks these current property values and saves it irrespective of whether it has changed or not.

I tried to change it to something like this:

```
    private bool _isDirty;
    private bool _showTaskBar;

    public bool ShowTaskBar
    {
        get { return _showTaskBar; }
        set
        {
            _showTaskBar = value;
            _isDirty = true;
        }
    }
```

but the problem is that _isDirty becomes true in the beginning only when the set is called for first time before binding the value. Hence, when user presses "OK" it always finds it true.

Is there any way to check if the value has changed with some property like IsDirty instead of putting a check where we compare the property value with initial value (in that case I think I need to cache the initial value and then compare, which seems to be too much to write)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `set { if (value != _showTaskBar) { _showTaskBar = value; _isDirty = true; } }` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this with a wrapper struct.

```
public struct DirtyableProperty<T>
{
   private T _value;

   public bool IsDirty { get; private set; }

   public T Value 
   { 
       get { return _value; }
       set
       {
            IsDirty |= !EqualityComparer<T>.Equals(value, _value);
            _value = value;
       }
   }

   public void LoadValue(T savedValue) { _value = savedValue; }

   public void MarkSaved() { IsDirty = false; }
}
```

Now when you load from persistence you call LoadValue instead of the setter and it doesn't mark the dirty flag.  When you go to save, if the property is dirty you call MarkSaved() and you're good to go.